Primeng - TieredMenu not showing, seems to be empty
My component :
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('fr'); // Langue par défaut
    this.translateService.use('fr'); // Utiliser la langue choisie

    this.accountService.getAuthenticationState().subscribe(account => {
      this.isAuthenticated = account !== null;

      if (this.isAuthenticated && account) {
        this.canSeeLogout = account.authorities.includes('ROLE_ADMIN') || account.authorities.includes('ROLE_USER');
      }

      this.buildMenu();
    });
  }
buildMenu(): void {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'File',
        icon: 'pi pi-file',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'New',
            icon: 'pi pi-plus',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Document',
                icon: 'pi pi-file',
              },
              {
                label: 'Image',
                icon: 'pi pi-image',
              },
              {
                label: 'Video',
                icon: 'pi pi-video',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: 'Open',
            icon: 'pi pi-folder-open',
          },
          {
            label: 'Print',
            icon: 'pi pi-print',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Edit',
        icon: 'pi pi-file-edit',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Copy',
            icon: 'pi pi-copy',
          },
          {
            label: 'Delete',
            icon: 'pi pi-times',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Search',
        icon: 'pi pi-search',
      },
      {
        separator: true,
      },
      {
        label: 'Share',
        icon: 'pi pi-share-alt',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Slack',
            icon: 'pi pi-slack',
          },
          {
            label: 'Whatsapp',
            icon: 'pi pi-whatsapp',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

html :
<p-tieredMenu [model]="items" [popup]="true" #menu></p-tieredMenu>

My menu seems to be empty, I can't see anything. I am getting :
<p-tieredmenu _ngcontent-ng-c2226474418="" class="p-element" ng-reflect-model="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-popup="true">
    <!--bindings={}-->
</p-tieredmenu>

I don't see what's wrong in what I have done. If anybody can help me on this...

TieredMenu with [popup]="true" is a popup menu component that requires an outside action in order to be displayed.
Based on your example I haven't seen any toggle actions performed to your tieredMenu component.
You would need to have a button or another component that will trigger tieredMenu, example:
<p-button label="Toggle" (onClick)="menu.toggle($event)" />
<p-tieredMenu #menu [model]="items" [popup]="true" />

If you want to keep it displayed always without any toggle options, then you can update your code to:
<p-tieredMenu #menu [model]="items" />

Below is the example of using TieredMenu:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/4xoiy4-5i9p56?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftiered-menu-popup-demo.html
